# What is the difference between two template types and two template parameter lists?

Tags: c++, templates

What is the difference between these two declaractions?
`template<typename T, typename U>`
`template<typename T> template<typename U>`

This was vaguely explained in the accepted answer on this question:
["too many template-parameter-lists" error when specializing a member function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3595859/too-many-template-parameter-lists-error-when-specializing-a-member-function)

I understand that they are not the same thing, but I'm having trouble finding resources that teach usage of the latter. Explanation and examples would be much appreciated.

Comment: There is no difference between them - both of them are not declarations.

Comment: I'm fairly certain there is indeed a difference, as one will generate a compile error and the other will not for a block of code I have in front of me. I'm also fairly certain that these could be considered declarations. They are declaring template types.

Comment: No, they don't declare template types. Class template declaration might look like `template<typename T, typename U> class C{/*...*/};` but not like you wrote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider a function template that needs two types. This would require two parameters:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
bool isEqual(const T &t, const U &u) {
    return t == u;
}
```

Now consider a class template with a member function template. This would require two lists:

```
template<typename T>
struct Foo {
    template<typename U>
    void bar(const U &u);
};

template<typename T>
template<typename U>
void Foo<T>::bar(const U &u) {/*do something with u*/}
```

Comment: Ah, that makes perfect sense. Looking back at the accepted answer for the linked question, that explained it, too. The wording just threw me off. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen if you specialize a class template with another type template. See, for example, how `MyTemplateClass` is specialized on a type `SomeRandomClass` in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4200397

Quoting in case it changes:

```
template <>
template <typename T,typename S>
class MyTemplateClass <SomeRandomClass<T,S> >
{
    void DoSomething(SomeRandomClass<T,S>& t) { /* something */ }
};
```